# Which playready version does IE11/Edge support now?

Tags: internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

I couldn't find any official document which could tell me the supported playready version for IE11 or Edge.
Do they support the latest playready version 3.0?
Can I use playready header object 4.2.0.0 for the latest browser?
Basically I want to implement playready protected dash streaming on IE11/Edge. I would like to confirm which version I should use.
I will appreciate if anyone could give me an answer.

Comment: You may want to check this link. https://testweb.playready.microsoft.com/Doc/TestingClientInfo

Answer (score 1):

Short answer but no more to say I guess : **PlayReady 3.0** on Windows 10

Comment: From the log, I could see that the browsers are using Playready 3.1 SDK.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Edge/IE11 on windows10 at least is using playready 3.1 sdk.
If you want to use playready object header to acquire license, you must be very careful because even the official document of microsoft about proh isn't  compatible well with Edge/IE11. Not sure if it's bugs or on intention.